# UIImage Scaling PNG Image DOWN is Blurry

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to figure out what's going on and I've tried numerous solutions all to no avail.

I have a PNG image that is 354x354 @ 300dpi.  I'm loading that image into a UIImage and using the following code to **reduce** the size and its coming out very blurry.

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong?  Thanks.

```
//Image is 354x354
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( CGSizeMake(40.0, 40.0) );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:UIPasteboardNameGeneral create:NO];
[pasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];

//I'm then pasting the image into a UITexView and this is where it 
//shows up as blurry.

[self.textView paste:self];
```

Simple and remember I'm reducing the size and its coming back blurry.

Comment: What is `newSize`? You refer to it in your code but I don't see you setting it anywhere. - Also, how do you know the image is blurry? How do you know what it looks like at all? You do not show any code that would cause the image to be displayed. - Finally, please post the image somewhere so that others can try to reproduce.

Comment: I am getting same issue. Image showing proper in iPhone 6+ but it's loosing quality in iPhone 6!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect a 40x40 image to contain the same information as a 354x354 image. You are throwing away 123,716 pixels out of the original 125,316! That's 99% of the pixels!!!! Clearly some information is going to be lost.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't DOWN scaling preserve the clarity of the image.  I do this all of the time in Pixelmator, Photoshop etc... and it looks beautiful.  in IOS this is awful.

Comment: You still haven't posted the image so I still can't try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post any of the images because they are confidential for client.  If you wouldn't mind I can send you one offline.  Send me email at ch@upinteractivemedia.com

Comment: If you want help you need to provide enough information so that others can reproduce the issue. Try it with some other image that you _are_ allowed to post.